# I Can't Write Arabic text in the XAML file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

```
<TextBlock Text="المبلغ" />
```

when i built the project the following error happened:

[image]

any help....

Comment: What encoding is declared at the top of your file, and what are your Visual Studio settings for file encodings?

Comment: Are you sure it is the offending line? I didn't have any problems with it...

Comment: how to know the file encoding

Comment: @MohamedAhmed post your *root element* of the xaml file. This is the xml element at the very top of your file. Edit your question and paste this element to inform us about your root element.

Comment: my root element is the window tag <Window>

Comment: The problem is clear, you have a problem with your file encoding, because the word in the Text property up there is an Arabic keyword which requires Unicode encoding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is clear, you have a problem with your file encoding, If am not mistaken the word in the Text property up there is an Arabic keyword which requires Unicode encoding.
Change your file encoding to Unicode, by doing the following:

Open the XAML file you have problem with, go to File > Save As

[image]

Click on the small down arrow at the save button to select the encoding

[image]

Select Unicode save and replace your old file.

[image]

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Why Save As? Is it simpler to use Advanced Save Options and change encoding there? Instead of overwriting file. This is just below Save As option.

Answer (score 3):

Change the XAML file encoding to **"UTF-8"** , you can use Visual Studio to Save File As and then change the encoding.

Comment: File -> Save As -> click on the arrow beside the Save button and chose Save With Encoding and then choose Unicode

Answer (score 0):

To Change the encoding try this

```
var pi = xmldoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml",
                                " version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'");
xmldoc.appendChild(pi);
```

Check out the link below.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468560.aspx