# XamlReader and Umlauts

Tags: c#, wpf, encoding, xamlparseexception, xamlreader

I've got a xaml with a german umlaut (s. below) now when I try to parse it, I get an invalidchar error.

When I don't use an XamlParser Context it works. But I have to use it in order to set some type mappings

---

XAML:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:test="clr-namespace:BR.UI.Tests.Items;assembly=BR.UI.ViewLocator.Tests"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <test:SampleViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Label>ö</Label>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code which parses it

```
 var context = new ParserContext();
 var result = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(xaml,context);
```

I can't find anything to set an encoding hint (which would be .net String UTF-16) what am I doing wrong?

I also tried to inject the encoding with an XmlParserContext.

```
    var xmlcontext = new XmlParserContext(null, null, null, XmlSpace.Preserve,
                                          Encoding.Unicode);

    var context = new ParserContext(xmlcontext);
```

But it didn't help :-(

What do I need to do? Is there some kind of XAML encoding?

Comment: xaml is just xml; have you tried adding (since you say it is UTF-16) `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>` at the start? of course, I'm assuming that it *is* actually UTF-16...

Comment: When you save the XAML file are you saving with a 8, 16 or 32 bit encoding? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186484/i-cant-write-arabic-text-in-the-xaml-file

Comment: It was just a .net string so i assume UTF-16.
Btw when I Use XamlReader.Load(Stream...) ist works. really strange behavior :-(

Comment: Have you tried xml encoding it (e.g. &#246;)?

Comment: You shouldn't need the context to recognise your umlaut in XAML - what is the content of the variable xaml (which must be the XAML as a string) on the second line of the 'code which parses it'? I would imagine the problem is to do with the way you are reading in your XML to populate the variable 'xaml'.

Comment: I need the context for mapping dependent assemblies (i cut this here out to make the example simpler)

the xaml variable contains the xaml string. The problem also occurs when i just create the string in code without any files .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question hope that is ok.

What helped for me was using the

`System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(stream,XamlParserContext)`

Method.

s. http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms590388.aspx

This method seems to respect the encoding of the string variable.

I still don't understand why this doesn't work with the Static ParseMethod. But I hope this solution will help someone else to safe time :-)

Comment: I think you should mark your own answer as "the answer" to this question, since it actually solves the problem.