# Special characters (like Ü,Ä,Ö) are not correctly displayed at runtime in case of using Template10

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, uwp, template10

Have an issue by using the Template10 for UWP apps. If i want to display special characters at design time everything seems to be ok. At runtime special characters would not be displayed correctly as you can see in screenshots.

```
<!--  page header  -->
    <controls:PageHeader Content="Übersicht">
        <controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoSettings}" Label="Settings" />
            <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoPrivacy}" Label="Privacy" />
            <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoAbout}" Label="About" />
        </controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
    </controls:PageHeader>
```

For example "**Ü**bersicht"
-> VisualStudio Designer "**Ü**bersicht"
-> Runtime "?bersicht"

**Designer view**

[image]

**Runtime**

[image]

Comment: For future reference, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10186640/6496980. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use string resources (.resw files), the characters will also appear correctly:

XAML: x:Uid="..."

C#: ResourceLoader.GetForViewIndependentUse().GetString("...");

Comment: Using string resources solves the problem. Thanks for your post Luis. But i do not understand why this is just happening if i use template10. In case of default visual studio uwp template i do not have to use string resources and special characters would be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set your [PrimaryLanguageOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.applicationlanguages.aspx)?

You're dealing with UTF-8 by default, so I'd normally expect it to be fine but in this instance if you don't wish to set your localization you can substitute [unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) `&#220;` to reliably display Ü

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris. I was looking the solution for this override (also template 10 project) and cant found this method call.