# UWP cannot display Chinese Characters properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-template-studio

I'm using the updated Windows Template Studio in VS2017 to design a UWP app. However some Chinese Characters cannot be displayed properly. If these characters are added in C#, then it works well, but when added in XAML, it becomes blocks.

This is an example. You can see that the headers, originally Chinese, become interesting.

What should I do? Thx~!

[image]
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135623/special-characters-like-%C3%9C-%C3%84-%C3%96-are-not-correctly-displayed-at-runtime-in-case-o

Comment: @devin Thx a lot

Comment: also try to use different font family

Comment: @Shubham thx but what fontfamily should i use for chinese?

Comment: You can download Chinese font or may be you have pre installed  , so just locate the name of that font using character map or  MSWord and view name of font in your  TextBlock e.g FontFamily="Your Font Name"
So when you build your project that font will part of your app

Answer (score 0):

You Should Customize your pivot at this level

```
<Pivot>
      <PivotItem Header="YourItemNAme">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="15" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                        Some Description
                    </TextBlock>                        
                        <TextBlock Name="AnyName" FontSize="35" Margin="0,15,0,0"
                                   FontFamily="Your Font Name" Text="your  that font supported text" />                                                                             
                </StackPanel>                    
       </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

Comment: Additionally you can use relative panel for more better arrangement of data

Comment: Thx a lot @shubham

Comment: Check this solution, if it is work you can mark this as answer and dont mark this as answer until it is not work for you